# Storing US employer identification number (EIN / FEIN) in a database

Tags: privacy, databases

What are considerations for storing a United States [Employer Identification Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Employer_Identification_Number) ([EIN / FEIN](http://www.irs.gov/businesses/small/article/0,,id=98350,00.html)) in a database?
Is this considered sensitive information along the lines of an SSN?
Are there legal concerns as well?

Comment: In case anyone else needs to look it up: EIN is  employer identification number which the IRS uses to identify businesses for tax purposes.  http://www.irs.gov/businesses/small/article/0,,id=98350,00.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The EIN is publicly available information, so it is not generally as sensitive as a SSN.
- Nevertheless, you may need to secure it for other reasons depending on your circumstances. e.g. could a competitor use it to figure out your customer list?
- As ever, get your legal advice from a lawyer licensed in the relevant jurisdiction, not from some schmuck like me on the Internet.